# Coppermine Gallery CSS code error

Tags: html, css, gallery

I'm making a Coppermine theme all by myself. It's not that hard, I have to say. But I have a problem... [This](http://danithemes.fanscity.eu/designs) is my gallery. As you can see, I can't place the gallery itself below the main header. I mean, it's not in the middle, right below the header.

HTML CODE:

```
  <div id="cpg_main_block">
    {MESSAGE_BLOCK} {GALLERY} 
{CUSTOM_FOOTER} {CREDITS}
</div>
```

CSS CODE:

```
#cpg_main_block {
    background-color:#transparent;
    width: 1100px;
    margin-left:150px;
}
```

Besides, the main header has space between the top of the page.How can I fix that too?

**Thank you SO much. This forum has been really helpful to me.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand you are looking to center the gallery under your header. This should do the trick.

Change your margin-left to auto,

```
margin-left: auto;
```

And add this:

```
margin-right: auto;
```

Your final result should look like this:

```
#cpg_main_block {
background-color:#transparent;
width: 1100px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

}